# Finding children of Gustav Steinhauer (1870-1930)

Tags: germany, birth-records

I am trying to find out if Gustav Steinhauer, lived 1870 to 1930 had children and if so where were they born and when.

I am trying to find out if I am related to Gustav Steinhauer

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than just posting a broad request for any information.

Comment: How do you know that Gustav Steinhauer lived 1870 to 1930?  Do you know where he lived?  Why do you think that you may be related to him?